# how to get first element of tuples with matching second element (python)

Tags: python

how to get first element of tuples with matching second element
the expected behavior is

```
('John','P')
('Mary','P') 
getAll('P')
```

which returns `['John','Mary']`

Answer (score 3):

The following function allows you to filter as desired:

```
data = [('John','P'), ('Mary','P')]

def getAll(mydata, key):
    return [item[0] for item in mydata if item[1] == key]
```

This uses a list comprehension that includes the first element of the tuple but only when the second element of the tuple matches `key` (in your example `'P'`).

Answer (score 2):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> lis = [ ('John','P'), ('Mary','P') ]
def getall(my_list, s):
    return [x for x, y in my_list if y==s]
... 
>>> getall(lis, 'P')
['John', 'Mary']
```

If you're doing this multiple times then it's better to use a dictionary here:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for v, k in lis:
...     d[k].append(v)
...     
>>> d['P']
['John', 'Mary']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of these tuples?  This answer doesn't use a list comprehension, for simplicity.  If you're asking this question, you probably don't know what a list comprehension is.

```
def get_all(foo, that_list):
    new_list = []
    for item in that_list:
        if item[1] == foo:
            new_list.append(item[0])
    return new_list

some_list = [('John', 'P'), ('Mary', 'P')]
get_all('P', some_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[t[0] for t in list_of_tuples if t[1] == 'P']
```